# How to cancel scrolling when scroll to a specific position in Android Scrollview?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a problem while scrolling in Scrollview. I would like to cancel scrolling immediately when I've scrolled to a specific position (like end of scrollview). That means my finger is still held on screen, but Scrollview can't scroll anymore. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does it does this already?.. Anyway, any code to share?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
   if (!mScrollable) return false;
     else return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me. When i reach end of scrollview, while my finger still on screen, scrolling didn't disable permanently. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel/stop scroll when you have reached particular position, you can use smoothScrollToPosition(int pos), where pos is the adapter position.

Also to make it a smooth experience for user, you can tell the listview to post it when ui thread is free:

```
getListView().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
    }
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. I detected when to reach end of Scrollview to cancel scroll, but if i reach end then scroll up again while still holding my finger, it can't cancel scroll :(